# ggplot2: How to get different color ribbons above and below a reference line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data to make a `geom_ribbon` and then a `geom_line` over it. And now, I would like to make the part of the ribbon above the red line, coloured differently.

### [image]

Data data for the plot:

```
#simulate data
dat <- data.frame(1:12)
colnames(dat) <- c("code")
dat$code <- month.abb
dat$code <- factor(dat$code, levels = dat$code)
dat$Th <- c(42, 44, 53, 64, 75, 83, 87, 84, 78, 67, 55, 45)
dat$Tl <- c(27, 28, 35, 44, 54, 63, 68, 66, 59, 48, 38, 29)
dat$prec <- c(3.03, 2.48, 3.23, 3.15, 4.13, 3.23, 4.13, 4.88, 3.82, 3.07, 2.83, 2.8)
dat$prec <- dat$prec*16
dat

#plot
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = code, ymin = Tl, ymax = Th)) +
  geom_ribbon(group = 1) +
  geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = code, y = prec, group = 2), colour = "red", size = 3) +
  expand_limits(y = 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by creating two ribbons, one between `Tl` and `prec` and one between `prec` and `Th`. In each case, we also need to address the case where `prec` is below or above, respectively, both `Th` and `Tl`:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = code)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pmin(pmax(prec,Tl),Th), ymax=Th, group=1), fill="blue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Tl, ymax=pmax(pmin(prec,Th),Tl), group=2), fill="green") +
  geom_line(aes(y = prec, group = 2), colour = "red", size = 3) +
  expand_limits(y = 0)
```

But note that the plot is not quite right because of the limited horizontal resolution of the data:

[image]

So let's create a new data frame that linearly interpolates the actual data at a bunch of points between each month and create the plot again:

```
dat.new = cbind.data.frame(
  code=seq(1,12,length=200), 
  sapply(dat[,c("prec","Th","Tl")], function(T) approxfun(dat$code, T)(seq(1,12,length=200)))
  )

ggplot(dat.new, aes(x = code)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pmin(pmax(prec,Tl),Th), ymax=Th, group=1), fill="blue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Tl, ymax=pmax(pmin(prec,Th),Tl), group=2), fill="green") +
  geom_line(aes(y = prec, group = 2), colour = "red", size = 3) +
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:12, labels=month.abb)
```

[image]