# ggplot2: More separate ribbons defined by one line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a climagraph, where I used `geom_ribbon` to show, where are precipitations lower than temperature.

But as I defined the `geom_ribbon` on one line, it wants to connect its halves in one, so it makes such fragment of grey "line", as you can see on the image.

Do you have any ideas how to get rid of this fragment?

[image]

```
tit <- "Name"
subtit <- "280 m a.s.l., 8.5 °C, 500 mm"

abb<- c("J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D") 
magnify <- 2
dat<-as.data.frame(1:12)
dat$'1:12' <- clim$code
names(dat) <- ("code")
dat$T<-c(-4.2,-0.6,8.6,19.0,28.4,34.8,38.4,38.2,29.6,18.6,8.0,-0.8)
dat$prec<-c(26,23,31,28,60,72,61,40,10,20,36,35)
dat$code <- factor(1:12, levels = 1:12)
dat$T <- dat$T * magnify
head(dat)
dat.new = cbind.data.frame(
  code=seq(1,12,length=200), 
  sapply(dat[,c("prec","T")], function(T) approxfun(dat$code, T)(seq(1,12,length=200)))
)    
#subsetting data
cut_max <- (dat.new$prec>=dat.new$T)
cut_min <- (dat.new$prec<=dat.new$T)
sub_max <- dat.new[cut_max, ]
sub_min <- dat.new[cut_min, ]
```

Plotting:

```
#plotting
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat.new, aes(x = code)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = sub_max, aes(ymin = T, ymax = prec), alpha = 0.5, fill = "grey25") +
  #geom_ribbon(data = sub_min, aes(ymin = T, ymax = prec), fill = "red", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = prec, group = 1), colour = "blue", size = 1.5, alpha = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = T, group = 1), colour = "red", size = 1.5, alpha = 1) +
  expand_limits(y = 0, ymax = 200) +
  geom_line(aes(y = 0, group = 1), size = 0.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))+
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Precipitation (mm)', 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . * (1/magnify), name = 'Temperature (°C)')) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=16, family="Comic Sans MS"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:12, labels=abb)+
  labs(title = tit, subtitle = subtit)
```

Comment: You can use a technique similar to the one in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41663887/496488) to the question you asked yesterday, except that you want both ymin and ymax to be equal to the value of the red line for those x values where temperature is greater than the precipitation (so that the ribbon will be a thin line directly under the red line and will therefore be invisible).

Comment: A couple of other things: You might want to make the axis titles (and maybe the axis text) color blue for precipitation and red for temperature to make it easier to see which axis applies to each curve. Also, to save some typing, you can do `abb = substr(month.abb, 1,1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up "groups" that will plot together, which will keep them separate from members of other groups by setting the `group` aesthetic. Often, this is used to make many identically lines (or similar) for separate units/individuals. In your case, you want it to be for separate portions of the graph where you are trying to plot.

Because your data does not have any natural groups, you will need to create them. Here, I am using `dplyr` to do a few manipulations on the data to create a new version of your `sub_max` that will have groups in it. First, I created a column saying whether or not we are keeping that row. Next, I set a flag to show when a portion we want to highlight starts and when the next portion we do *not* want to highlight starts. Then, I set groups up based on that flag (so that all rows in a section share the same group number. Finally, I keep only the rows that we want to highlight in.

```
newSubMax <-
  dat.new %>%
  mutate(toKeep = prec > T
         , changed = toKeep != lag(toKeep, default = toKeep[1])
         , group = cumsum(changed)) %>%
  filter(toKeep)
```

Now, we just replace your old `geom_ribbon` with the new data, and add `group = group` to the `aes` mapping. Just that line is now:

```
geom_ribbon(data = newSubMax
            , aes(ymin = T
                  , ymax = prec
                  , group = group)
            , alpha = 0.5, fill = "grey25")
```

and the whole plot code is:

```
ggplot(dat.new, aes(x = code)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = newSubMax
              , aes(ymin = T
                    , ymax = prec
                    , group = group)
              , alpha = 0.5, fill = "grey25") +
  #geom_ribbon(data = sub_min, aes(ymin = T, ymax = prec), fill = "red", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = prec, group = 1), colour = "blue", size = 1.5, alpha = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = T, group = 1), colour = "red", size = 1.5, alpha = 1) +
  expand_limits(y = 0, ymax = 200) +
  geom_line(aes(y = 0, group = 1), size = 0.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))+
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Precipitation (mm)', 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . * (1/magnify), name = 'Temperature (°C)')) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        text=element_text(size=16, family="Comic Sans MS"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:12, labels=abb)+
  labs(title = tit, subtitle = subtit)
```

giving

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I like your answer, as it is more complex. But I have finaly done it the way eipi10 mentioned in his coment. I just hid it under precipitation blue line.